# Pandas reorder rows of dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I stumble upon very peculiar problem in Pandas. I have this dataframe

```
,time,id,X,Y,theta,Vx,Vy,ANGLE_FR,DANGER_RAD,RISK_RAD,TTC_DAN_LOW,TTC_DAN_UP,TTC_STOP,SIM
0,1600349033921610000,0,23.2643889,-7.140948599999999,0,0.020961,-1.1414197,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,2.0,3
1,1600349033921620000,1,18.5371406,-14.224917,0,-0.0113912,1.443597,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,2.0,3
2,1600349033921650000,2,19.808648100000006,-6.778450599999998,0,0.037289,-1.0557937,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,2.0,3
3,1600349033921670000,3,22.1796988,-5.7078115999999985,0,0.2585675,-1.2431861000000002,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,2.0,3
4,1600349033921670000,4,20.757325,-16.115366,0,-0.2528627,0.7889673,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,2.0,3
5,1600349033921690000,5,20.9491012,-17.7806833,0,0.5062633,0.9386511,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,2.0,3
6,1600349033921690000,6,20.6225258,-5.5344404,0,-0.1192678,-0.7889041,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,2.0,3
7,1600349033921700000,7,21.8077004,-14.736984,0,-0.0295737,1.3084618,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,2.0,3
8,1600349033954560000,0,23.206789800000006,-7.5171016,0,-0.1727971,-1.1284589,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,2.0,3
9,1600349033954570000,1,18.555421300000006,-13.7440508,0,0.0548418,1.4426004,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,2.0,3
10,1600349033954570000,2,19.8409748,-7.126075500000002,0,0.0969802,-1.0428747,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,2.0,3
11,1600349033954580000,3,22.3263185,-5.9586202,0,0.4398591,-0.752425,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,2.0,3
12,1600349033954590000,4,20.7154136,-15.842398800000002,0,-0.12573430000000002,0.8189016,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,2.0,3
13,1600349033954590000,5,21.038901,-17.4111883,0,0.2693992,1.108485,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,2.0,3
14,1600349033954600000,6,20.612499,-5.810969,0,-0.030080400000000007,-0.8295869,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,2.0,3
15,1600349033954600000,7,21.7872537,-14.3011986,0,-0.0613401,1.3073578,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,2.0,3
16,1600349033921610000,0,23.2643889,-7.140948599999999,0,0.020961,-1.1414197,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,1.5,2
17,1600349033954560000,0,23.206789800000003,-7.5171016,0,-0.1727971,-1.1284589,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,1.5,2
18,1600349033988110000,0,23.21602,-7.897527,0,0.027693000000000002,-1.1412761999999999,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,1.5,2
```

This is input file [image: Input]

**Please note that Id always starts at 0 up to 7 and repeat and time column is in sequential step (which implies that previous row should be smaller or equal to current one).**

I would like to reorder rows of the dataframe as it is below.

```
,time,id,X,Y,theta,Vx,Vy,ANGLE_FR,DANGER_RAD,RISK_RAD,TTC_DAN_LOW,TTC_DAN_UP,TTC_STOP,SIM
0,1600349033921610000,0,23.2643889,-7.140948599999999,0,0.020961,-1.1414197,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,1.0,2
1,1600349033954560000,0,23.206789800000003,-7.5171016,0,-0.1727971,-1.1284589,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,1.0,2
2,1600349033988110000,0,23.21602,-7.897527,0,0.027693000000000002,-1.1412761999999999,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,1.0,2
3,1600349033921610000,0,23.2643889,-7.140948599999999,0,0.020961,-1.1414197,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,1.5,1
4,1600349033954560000,0,23.206789800000003,-7.5171016,0,-0.1727971,-1.1284589,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,1.5,1
5,1600349033988110000,0,23.21602,-7.897527,0,0.027693000000000002,-1.1412761999999999,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,1.5,1
6,1600349033921610000,0,23.2643889,-7.140948599999999,0,0.020961,-1.1414197,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,1.5,2
7,1600349033954560000,0,23.206789800000003,-7.5171016,0,-0.1727971,-1.1284589,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,1.5,2
8,1600349033988110000,0,23.21602,-7.897527,0,0.027693000000000002,-1.1412761999999999,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,1.5,2
9,1600349033921610000,0,23.2643889,-7.140948599999999,0,0.020961,-1.1414197,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,1.5,3
10,1600349033954560000,0,23.206789800000003,-7.5171016,0,-0.1727971,-1.1284589,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,1.5,3
11,1600349033988110000,0,23.21602,-7.897527,0,0.027693000000000002,-1.1412761999999999,20,0.5,0.9,-1,7,1.5,3
```

This is the desired result [image: Output]

Please note that I need to reorder dataframe rows based on this columns id, time, ANGLE_FR, DANGER_RAD, RISK_RAD, TTC_DAN_LOW, TTC_DAN_UP, TTC_STOP, SIM.

As you see from the desired result we need to reoder dataframe in that way **time** column from smallest to largest one this holds true for the rest of columns, id, sim, ANGLE_FR, DANGER_RAD, RISK_RAD, TTC_DAN_LOW, TTC_DAN_UP, TTC_STOP.

I tried to sort by several columns without success. Moreover, I tried to use groupby but I failed.
Would you like to help to solve the problem? Any suggestions are welcome.

P.S.

**I have paste dataframe so they can be read easily with clipboard function in order to be easily reproducible.**

I am attaching pic as well.

Comment: You just need to sort by the `time` column right? I dont get what the issue it

Comment: @Serial Lazer   I cannot get the same result.

Comment: So you just want to ignore the `id` index and have all of them map to `0`, is it?

Comment: Nope. I want to group them as it is colored in pic. I need them to be group by  id, time, ANGLE_FR, DANGER_RAD, RISK_RAD, TTC_DAN_LOW, TTC_DAN_UP, TTC_STOP, SIM. Please bear in mind that this is sample of data. There is numerous combinations between the mentioned columns.

Comment: I add new rows in input file please note in order to capture some edge cases!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you try to sort by several columns?

```
In [10]: df.sort_values(['id', 'time', 'ANGLE_FR', 'DANGER_RAD', 'RISK_RAD', 'TTC_DAN_LOW', 'TTC_DAN_UP', 'TTC_STOP', 'SIM'])                                                                                      
Out[10]: 
    Unnamed: 0                 time  id        X        Y  theta      Vx      Vy  ANGLE_FR  DANGER_RAD  RISK_RAD  TTC_DAN_LOW  TTC_DAN_UP  TTC_STOP  SIM
0            0  1600349033921610000   0  23.2644  -7.1409      0  0.0210 -1.1414        20         0.5       0.9           -1           7         2    3
8            8  1600349033954560000   0  23.2068  -7.5171      0 -0.1728 -1.1285        20         0.5       0.9           -1           7         2    3
1            1  1600349033921620000   1  18.5371 -14.2249      0 -0.0114  1.4436        20         0.5       0.9           -1           7         2    3
9            9  1600349033954570000   1  18.5554 -13.7441      0  0.0548  1.4426        20         0.5       0.9           -1           7         2    3
2            2  1600349033921650000   2  19.8086  -6.7785      0  0.0373 -1.0558        20         0.5       0.9           -1           7         2    3
```

Comment: Yes but it not give me the desired result.

Comment: The *SIM* Column is not group e.g. it sorted as 2, 1 not 1 1 and 2, 2

Comment: If we add to *SIM* not only 3 let say 2 it is sorted 2, 3. If we have multiple occurrence of 2 and 3 it will sort them based on 2, 3 not group them same occurrence of 2 in same bracket.

Comment: I need you to apologize. You are right. Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
groupby_cols = ['ANGLE_FR', 'DANGER_RAD', 'RISK_RAD', 'TTC_DAN_LOW', 'TTC_DAN_UP', 'TTC_STOP, SIM']
df = df.groupby(groupby_cols).reset_index()
```

Comment: AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'reset_index' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Comment: I add new rows in order to capture some edge cases!